# Как добавить разные данные в несколько таблиц в Postgres?

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

Как добавить разные данные в несколько таблиц в Postgres?
Через INSERT INTO можно указать несколько таблиц?

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO принимает только одну таблицу для вставки.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 1):

а для чего это нужно? данные одной таблицы зависят от другой? думаю если нужен ид последней вставленной записи то `returning id`. а если одноуровневые таблицы (предположим на разных серверах) - то можете хоть через `;` писать. 
если данные из одного запроса сразу использовать в другом то

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT f.x, f.y, bar_id, b.z
    FROM   foo f
    JOIN   bar b ON b.id = f.bar_id
    WHERE  x > 3
    ),b AS (
    INSERT INTO bar (z)
    SELECT z
    FROM   a
    RETURNING z, id AS bar_id
    )
INSERT INTO foo (x, y, bar_id)
SELECT a.x, a.y, b.bar_id
FROM   a
JOIN   b USING (z);
```

[полный ответ здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t)